# R: index vector with same index for duplicates

Tags: r, indexing, duplicates

I have a dataframe with 15k rows and 45 columns (including integers, dates, strings, booleans,...).

`var1   var2    var3
FS      12      31.12.2016
BX      65      30.06.2016
BI      28      31.03.2016
FS      12      31.12.2016`

Some of these rows are identical. I now need an additional column containing some kind of index with identical entries for identical rows like the 1st and 4th row in this example:

`index  var1    var2    var3
1       FS      12      31.12.2016
2       BX      65      30.06.2016
3       BI      28      31.03.2016
1       FS      12      31.12.2016`

I could use a hash function, but that would destroy the original row order. Ideally it would be an increasing number like in my example.
I tried my luck with `duplicated()`, but it seems like that is intended mainly for deduplication.
Also, I could write loops to compare all lines and derive the right index, but there probably is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "-")))`

Comment: That doesn't start with 1, but it absolutely suits my need. Thank you very much for the swift help!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df=data.frame(var1=c("FS","BX","BI","FS"),var2=c(12,65,28,12))
df2 = df%>%group_by(var1,var2)%>%mutate(index=row_number())%>%ungroup()
```